# Burninate [extract]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The [extract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extract) tag has approximately 1900 questions, most of which are related in some way to the extraction of some bit of information from some larger bit of information.  It [has a tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/extract/info), but it has only ever had one revision and indeed the wiki description looks to have been assembled from the types of questions using the tag rather than offer guidance as to how it should be used.

The tag's usage is all over the map:.

Lots refer to extraction of substrings (such as via regular expression)

- [How to extract img src, title and alt from html using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138313/how-to-extract-img-src-title-and-alt-from-html-using-php)
- [How to extract a substring using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662215/java-how-to-extract-a-substring-using-regex)
- *the majority are like these....*

Some refer to extraction or refactoring of code from an existing codebase or VCS:

- [How do I move a Git branch out into its own repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227062/how-do-i-move-a-git-branch-out-into-its-own-repository)
- [Create a new repo from sub folder in Mercurial Repo using convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843479/create-a-new-repo-from-sub-folder-in-mercurial-repo-using-convert)

Some refer to extracting archive files.

- [ZipInputStream getNextEntry is null when extracting .zip files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561031/zipinputstream-getnextentry-is-null-when-extracting-zip-files)
- [Batch - Extract many zip, rename files extracted in a same directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15328718/batch-extract-many-zip-rename-files-extracted-in-a-same-directory)

Some refer to other things entirely

- [Algorithms for named entity recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026925/algorithms-for-named-entity-recognition)

The diversity of applications for [extract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extract) suggest it isn't that useful. **Can we burninate it?**

Comment: ...waiting for anyone to pipe up and claim they're an "extraction" expert... nope... Burn it! Burn it with fire!

Comment: @Matt There are clearly at least 4 people who consider themselves extraction experts or enthusiasts. The tag has 4 followers.

Comment: I feel like each one of the example categories you provided has a synonym which is better suited (the first set, for example, is better described as *parsing*). Burn it, I agree.

Comment: If you make yourself coffee or tea, you're an extraction expert :)

Answer (score 47):

Your arguments are solid for burninating it. I can't see the utility of browsing the tag or seeing it tagged in a question.

Comment: Nothing personal, but that's a lot of upvotes for basically saying "I agree".

Comment: hey, I had to do a lot of research for my answer! :)

Comment: @Cerbrus People express their agreement by upvoting this agreement.