# Extracting [extract]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The [extract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extract) was proposed for burnination [two years ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260827/burninate-extract) but it is still alive today.

I think we should burn it, along with its synonym [extraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extraction).

Comment: Thanks for posting this request and allowing the community to weigh in! Please note that burninating a tag is the process of carefully moderating a specific piece of Stack Overflow (please think twice before doing tag-only mass edits, as they can be counter-productive); once the community reaches a consensus, burnination can proceed. For more info, see [Shog9's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/306392) on MSE or the [unofficial SOCVR process](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323121/4174897) on MSO.

Answer (score 5):

The original question had pretty strong arguments in favor of burning that tag, so I will reproduce the most relevant and add some more:

### The tag is all over the place

Python, html, regex, R, php, you call it. Extraction has it. It isn't even strongly tied with a language or group of languages.

### The topic is all over the place

The tag excerpt says "Questions related to retrieving specific information from a data source". It doesn't describe in a concrete manner what methodology should be followed, nor the structure of the data source. Which only leave us the last point...

### The tag is a verb/task

Like [delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delete), [create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/create), [update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/update), etc. it doesn't says anything useful about the question they are associated with that people can specialize into. You will need to read the whole question to know the source, the method and the broad limitations that you have to take into account.